# How to compare two string value and give back which is not exits?

Tags: c#

Here I have two string as:

```cs
string a1 = "A1,A2,A3,B1-1,B2-1";
string a2 = "A1,A2,A3,B1-1,B2-1,A4,A5";
```

Here `A4` and `A5` do not exist in `a1`. How can I find them as new values?

```cs
string finalValue = string.compare(a1, a2);
```

Here I'm getting numeric value.

Comment: Are they always showing at the end of the string? or possible everywhere?

Comment: yes always string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```
var a = a1.Split(',');
var b = a2.Split(',');
var results = a.Except(b).Union(b.Except(a));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
```

**Output**

```
A4, A5
```

Essentially, it's just splitting the strings, using the `Except` method (both ways) and *unioning* the results

---

**Additional Resources**

[String.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
>   character array.

[Enumerable.Except Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8)

> Produces the set difference of two sequences.

[Enumerable.Union Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.8)

> Produces the set union of two sequences.

Comment: A4, B2-1, B2-2, B2-3, B2-4, D2, D3, ,B2-1,B2-2,B2-3,B2-4,D2,D3 its giving me all values

Comment: @MubeenGhouse working for me - https://dotnetfiddle.net/8onGLk

Answer (score 1):

separate both the string by using Split method and compare both list

```
List<string> list1 =  Arrays.asList(a1.Split(','));
List<string> list2 =  Arrays.asList(a2.Split(','));
```

If you want to get items from the first list except items in the second list, use

```
var differences = list1.Except(list2);
```